# Клонування - двійничення, множення чи подвоєння?

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Цікавить чи є в українській слово, яким можна було б замінити іншомовне "клонування".

**Клонування** -процес створення ідентичних копій (тиражування) організмів або інших об'єктів у біології.

Приклад вживання:

> На початку 70-х років XX ст. були розроблені методи **клонування**
>   бактерій та вищих рослин.

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/klonuvannia) ще немає остаточно вибраного варіанту, але серед запропонованих є такі: двійничення (цього слова немає в СУМі), подвоєння (знаходимо це слово в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/podvojennja), однак воно означає "збільшення в два рази"), множення (є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/mnozhennja), однак лише як математичний термін), відтворення (є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidtvorennja) і має значення: "Передавати що-небудь з максимальною точністю").

Отож, чи справді можна вважати слово "відтворення" відповідником до слова "клонування? І як тоді бути із словом "клон"? Адже тут, мені здається, найкращим відповідником буде "двійник".

Comment: Я б синонімами _клонування_ назвав: _копіювання_, _дублювання_ — але не знаю, наскільки вони Вас влаштують, бо вони теж нещодавнього іншомовного походження. «Словники України on-line» в ролі синоніма до _копіювати_ також пропонують _перебивати_ (в мене чомусь асоціація з дитячими перебивачками (напівпрозорими наклейками) початку 90-х) і _відтворювати_. Мабуть, найкращі еквіваленти — це справді _відтворити_ й _дубль/дублікат/копія/двійник_. Ні, звісно, повними відповідниками вони не будуть, адже значення цих слів значно ширші. Також є сумніви щодо _двійник_.

Comment: Оскільки _[двійник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21007&page=711)_ за словником передбачає зовнішню подобу. А клон може бути й не подібним зовнішньо через різні умови розвитку. І також бути досить віддаленим у часі (типу, якщо клонувати когось, коли він уже не дитина чи навіть зовсім старий, то вони з клоном будуть ззовні несхожі просто через різний вік).

Comment: А якщо обрати "відтворення" як відповідник, то як тоді замінити "клон"?

Comment: Іменник не зобов'язаний бути одного кореня з дієсловом. Але якщо дубль/дублікат/копія для Вас занадто закордонні — то поки що в мене ідей більше немає. Upd.: Хм, а як щодо використання загальніших слів типу _дитина_, _плід_ тощо?

Comment: Клонування - це  в і д т в о р е н н я  базового варіанту, а також "копіювання, дублювання" (як зазначив вище @Sasha).

Answer (score 1):

Cлово "відтворення" може вживатися як відповідник слову "клонування", оскільки обидва терміни означають процес створення ідентичних копій чогось. Щодо слова "клон", то "двійник" може бути відповідним варіантом. Також можна вживати слова "копія" або "репліка". Однак, варто зазначити, що слово "клонування" вже широко вживається в українській мові і має визнану наукову та технічну сферу застосування, тому в деяких випадках може бути виправданим його використання.